# Nested Child Elements with CanCan

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, nested, cancan

new to Ruby and working on changes for an in-house application.

I am using CanCan so that we can restrict access to pages.

I have the following code which works but I know that there's a better way that this can be written for an unknown amount of child elements.

A user has a line manager, who has a line manager... e.t.c. I am trying to achieve a tree hierarchy so that top line managers can view their staffs account, but only if they are part of the hierarchy of that staff. In the below example, John should be able to view Jane and Jack's profile, but not Josh or James'.

```
  +-------------+----------------------+--------+
  | user_id     | name                 | parent |
  +-------------+----------------------+--------+
  |           1 | JOHN SMITH           |   NULL |
  |           2 | JANE SMITH           |      1 |
  |           3 | JACK SMITH           |      2 |
  |           4 | JOSH SMITH           |      5 |
  |           5 | JAMES SMITH          |   NULL |
  +-------------+----------------------+--------+
```

Part of Ability.rb

```
class Ability
    include CanCan::Ability
    def initialize(user)
      user ||= User.new
      can :read, User, id: user.id
      can :read, User, line_manager: user
      can :read, User, line_manager: {line_manager: user}
      can :read, User, line_manager: {line_manager: {line_manager: user}}
      can :read, User, line_manager: {line_manager: {line_manager: {line_manager: user}}}
      can :read, User, line_manager: {line_manager: {line_manager: {line_manager: {line_manager: user}}}}
      can :read, User, line_manager: {line_manager: {line_manager: {line_manager: {line_manager: {line_manager: user}}}}}
```

I appreciate any assistance as this isn't a long term solution as the amount of nests can expand and requires to be done on more than just the user.

Comment: could you post your user and line managers class definition?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A performant solution would be to collect all the ids from the db in an array, and give the user access to them. A dirtier Solution without DB-Queries would be something like:

```
can :read, User.all do |r_user|
  until r_user.line_manager.nil? do |manager|
    return true if manager == user
    r_user = manager
  end
  return false
end
```

(Note the code is untested, but something like this should work).
But this would loop all the Users again and again. I would suggest to collect the id's with a query

Comment: Thanks Doktor. I ended up collecting the IDs as you mentioned in an array and iterated.

Comment: Thanks for the accepting. And I really don't like to endanger my points, but my answer did not much in terms of collecting ids. So I would suggest that you update your question with your current solution, maybe we can help you improve it further. And if it is allready a good solution, i'll be glad i helped you ;-)

Answer (score 0):

You could use the [closure_tree](https://github.com/mceachen/closure_tree) gem, which will allow you to manage hierarchy in your models. Then, you could add an instance method in your model like this:

```
def managed_by? user_id
  self_and_ancestors_ids.include? user_id
end
```

And you could then pass a block to your cancan abilities like this

```
can :read, User, User.all do |fetched_user|
  fetched_user.managed_by? user.id
end
```